# Comparing against strings

Tags: assembly, x86

Trying to learn assembly by compiling software and looking at small programs and seeing their output in IDA

Came across this which I'm stumped with

```
cmp     dword ptr [eax], 68323731h
```

The value of EAX is a pointer to a string, I'm just confused on what this is comparing it too? I thought originally this would be text in hexadecimal but trying to convert 68323731h to text produces garbage

Comment: `31h` is ASCII `'1'`, and the higher bytes are 3 more printable ASCII characters:   http://www.asciitable.com/.  For example 68h is `'h'`, and the middle two characters are also decimal digits.

Comment: can you show the source of the small program that resulted in this machine code?

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack: Something like `memcmp(str, "172h", 4)` could compile to this asm.  But yeah, understanding asm is usually easier when you actively look at the source that compiled to it.  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ which color-highlights and does mouseover bolding to match up source to asm.  (Using debug info generated by the compiler.)

Comment: @PeterCordes the closest i could get to was this: https://godbolt.org/z/oh4E9j9rh
funny how clang actually puts the constant in big-endian order and uses bswap on the value to be compared, seems quite unnecessary to me o.O

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack bswap is probably to make it return negative/positive correctly (if you put bytes in big endian order, then cmp result will be determined by the first non-equal byte, just like memcmp). Returning `memcmp(...) == 0` gets rid of bswap.